# Как в IIS разрешить Active Server Pages

Tags: iis

Для развертывание веб-приложения в IIS версии 10.0 необходимо в разрешить использование Active Server Pages, но я никак не могу найти, где это находится

Comment: По умолчанию компонент ASP не ставится. Нужно его установить вручную. Идём в "Удаление или изменение программ" > "Включение или отключение компонентов Windows". Находим Службы IIS, ставим галочку у ASP. Примерно так.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло